# jQuery Ajax sends empty escaped data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a mobile application which would connect to a site API.
I am sending the data through jQuery Ajax, but on escaping the data to be URL friendly, my GET parameter becomes empty when it reached the API.

i have the following jQuery/javascript code

```
var id = 012345;
var token = 55fggt98ujhsbnh;
var email = "sample@example.com";
var json = { // Create object
    "task" : "request",
    "id" : id, 
    "token" : token
};
var jsonfull = []; // Push to jsonfull.
jsonfull.push(json);
var url = JSON.stringify(json);
var crypt = '&hash='+CryptoJS.SHA512(token+task+email+url).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)+'&callback=?';
var x = 'json='+escape(url)+escape(crypt);
$.ajax({
    url: "mydemosite.com/?p=app&", 
    crossDomain: true,
    data: x,
    dataType: "jsonp"           
})
.done(function (json){ 
    alert(json.response);
});
```

On my php code where the data is sent i have the following code to receive the ajax data

```
$rest = $_GET['json'];
$api = json_decode($rest,true);
$type = 'json';
file_put_contents('logs/api_task.txt', print_r($_GET,true));
```

Checking the file where the content were saved i get this

```
Array
(
    [p] => app
    [callback] => jQuery1111006607784540392458_1446159115404
    [json] => {"task":"balance","merchant":"hifee","token":"1446159118-5632a30e2ed0f5632a30e2ed465614257"}&hash=0b645fac1f3ef3b5911435e58fbc1f157bd0273a01a664427b014fb517d9c46ae60e1d2fe3128d76d610706f9b8a9ac660517b77cbf4c3c6e02e597b065d1038&callback=?
    [_] => 1446159115406
)
```

Data i was hoping to get was

```
Array
(
    [p] => app
    [callback] => jQuery1111006607784540392458_1446159115404
    [json] => {"task":"balance","merchant":"hifee","token":"1446159118-5632a30e2ed0f5632a30e2ed465614257"}
    [hash] => 0b645fac1f3ef3b5911435e58fbc1f157bd0273a01a664427b014fb517d9c46ae60e1d2fe3128d76d610706f9b8a9ac660517b77cbf4c3c6e02e597b065d1038
)
```

I would appreciate any help i could get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are escaping your `crypt` variable and concatenating it to your JSON parameter value. With `escape` you also escaped `&` and everything becomes part of the `json` parameter.

It would be simpler, if you just passed the parameters as an object and let jQuery escape the values.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "mydemosite.com", 
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {
        p: "app",
        json: url,
        hash: CryptoJS.SHA512(token+task+email+url).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
    },
    dataType: "jsonp"           
})
.done(function (json){ 
    alert(json.response);
});
```

Comment: this works quite well. One more question, how do i pass the callback with the data sent?